# HBASE Record limit in scan api

Tags: hbase, limit, database-scan

Is there any java api to limit the number of scanned records after using start and stop rows?
Is pagefilter an option?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the [setMaxResultSize()](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setMaxResultSize%28long%29) ?

PageFilter may not give the expected results, the doc says:

> this filter cannot guarantee that the number of results returned to a
>   client are <= page size. This is because the filter is applied
>   separately on different region servers. It does however optimize the
>   scan of individual HRegions by making sure that the page size is never
>   exceeded locally.

Answer (score 1):

use scan.setLimit(int) method

https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setLimit-int-

> Set the limit of rows for this scan. We will terminate the scan if the number of returned rows reaches this value.
>   This condition will be tested at last, after all other conditions such as stopRow, filter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setCaching(int) might be able to help you. setCaching() is used to define how many results HBase should return in one RPC call.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer applies if you want to get a **single** row only*

If you're using an older version of HBase where [setLimit](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setLimit-int-) is not available, you could use [stopRow](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setStopRow(byte%5B%5D)) instead giving it the same value as [startRow](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setStartRow(byte%5B%5D)) and adding a trailing byte set to zero to make it inclusive, from the [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Scan.html#setStopRow(byte%5B%5D)):

> Note: In order to make stopRow inclusive add a trailing 0 byte

Here is an example:

```
    byte[] startRow = new byte[] { (byte)0xab, (byte)0xac};
    byte[] stopRow = new byte[startRow.length + 1];
    Array.copy(startRow, 0, stopRow, 0, startRow.length);
    stopRow[stopRow.length - 1] = 0; // inclusive
    Scan scan = new Scan().setStartRow(startRow).setStopRow(stopRow);
```